# Azure Builds is adding an extra folder (win-x64) causing build to break

Tags: azure, azure-devops, wix

Given:
Visual Studio 2019 Web API .Net Core 3.1
Wix Toolset 3.1.1 (latest)
Wix Toolset Extension for Visual Studio 2019
Windows 2016 Azure DevOps 2019

All I'm trying to do is use Wix Toolset to create an .msi file for a very simple WebAPI project.

The build works perfectly locally of course, but when it runs in Azure Builds I get following error because an extra folder is getting added (win-x64)

Here's a snippet of build script in Azure Pipelines:

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

> ication1\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\win-x64\publish\WebApplication1.exe'

```
Link:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\Light.exe -out C:\agent2\_work\4\s\SetupProject1\bin\Release\SetupProject1.msi -pdbout C:\agent2\_work\4\s\SetupProject1\bin\Release\SetupProject1.wixpdb -cultures:null -contentsfile obj\Release\SetupProject1.wixproj.BindContentsFileListnull.txt -outputsfile obj\Release\SetupProject1.wixproj.BindOutputsFileListnull.txt -builtoutputsfile obj\Release\SetupProject1.wixproj.BindBuiltOutputsFileListnull.txt -wixprojectfile C:\agent2\_work\4\s\SetupProject1\SetupProject1.wixproj obj\Release\Product.wixobj
  Windows Installer XML Toolset Linker version 3.11.2.4516
  Copyright (c) .NET Foundation and contributors. All rights reserved.

C:\agent2\_work\4\s\SetupProject1\Product.wxs(28): error LGHT0103: The system cannot find the file 'C:\agent2\_work\4\s\WebApplication1\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\win-x64\publish\WebApplication1.exe'. [C:\agent2\_work\4\s\SetupProject1\SetupProject1.wixproj]
##[error]SetupProject1\Product.wxs(28,0): Error LGHT0103: The system cannot find the file 'C:\agent2\_work\4\s\WebApplication1\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\win-x64\publish\WebApplication1.exe'.
C:\agent2\_work\4\s\SetupProject1\Product.wxs(31): error LGHT0103: The system cannot find the file 'C:\agent2\_work\4\s\WebApplication1\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\win-x64\publish\appsettings.json'. [C:\agent2\_work\4\s\SetupProject1\SetupProject1.wixproj]
##[error]SetupProject1\Product.wxs(31,0): Error LGHT0103: The system cannot find the file 'C:\agent2\_work\4\s\WebApplication1\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\win-x64\publish\appsettings.json'.
Done Building Project "C:\agent2\_work\4\s\SetupProject1\SetupProject1.wixproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "C:\agent2\_work\4\s\Solution1.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
```

Comment: Do you mean the files exist in `C:\agent2\_work\4\s\WebApplication1\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish`, but DevOps build indicate `C:\agent2\_work\4\s\WebApplication1\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\win-x64\publish`?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: You mentioned the build works perfectly locally, do you run the build on this build agent machine? Please try to set variable system.debug to True, and share the log.

Comment: Is the full Visual Studio required when using Wix? I just have the build tools?

Comment: What's the meaning of you just have the build tools? You mentioned you have Wix Toolset Extension for Visual Studio 2019. How do you build your project locally? Please try to run your build locally on your build agent machine to see how's the result.